# Getting a subset of an R data frame using values in the order vector

Tags: r, subset, correlation, dataframe

I have a vector of correlation scores `myCorVector` which contains a range of values from 1 to -1.

The vector `myCorVector` has a score for each row of a data frame `myDataFrame`.

I can order the data frame rows by specifying `myDataFrame[order(myCorVector),]`.

What I would like to do is order the data frame, but retrieve a subset of rows from `myDataFrame` where `myCorVector` values are less than 0.

If I apply `subset()` on `myCorVector`, then the indices returned by `order()` no longer associate with valid row indices in `myDataFrame`.

Is there a quick and/or elegant way to do this that doesn't require a `for` loop over `myCorVector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the scores to the data.frame, create a sorted copy and subset that:

```
myDataFrame$myCorVector <- myCorVector
odf <- myDataFrame[order(myDataFrame$myCorVector), ]
odf[odf$myCorVector < 0, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple index should do the job:

```
myDataFrame[order(myCorVector),][sort(myCorVector)<0,]
```

The tricky part is the order change imposed by `order`; without sorting it would be just:

```
myDataFrame[myCorVector<0,]
```